# How to replace @SchedulerLock with programmatic style

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, shedlock

I use spring boot and somewhere in code I have following code:

```
@SchedulerLock(name = "onlineIngestionTask", lockAtMostFor = 900, lockAtLeastFor = 900)
    public void pullTasksFromRemote() throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("task-started");
        Thread.sleep(500);
        logger.info("task-stopped");
    }
```

Is there way to replace it via programmatic style?

Comment: before execute pullTasksFromRemote get lock then release the lock

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You seem to be able to do it without Spring Annotations like said in the documentation: https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#running-without-spring

```
LockingTaskExecutor executor = new DefaultLockingTaskExecutor(lockProvider);

...

Instant lockAtMostUntil = Instant.now().plusSeconds(600);
executor.executeWithLock(runnable, new LockConfiguration("lockName", lockAtMostUntil));
```

Comment: in documentation said "without Spring"  Annotations not mentioned

Comment: He is using Shedlock. His question is tagged with it.

Comment: @gstackoverflow What do you mean? "Without Spring" and "without annotations" are, in this case, exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Michael,I didn't understand differents in semantics just pointed out in lexical difference. If it is the same - cool.

Comment: @Michael , what is default lockProvider ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow All the providers are [here](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock/tree/master/providers). I would guess that the Spring default is probably jdbc.

Comment: is there a scheduler like this executor ? LockingTaskExecutor ... not sure how do i give cron expression to executor

Comment: LockableTaskScheduler is for scheduling

Comment: The new one URL is: 
https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#running-without-spring